# End a Python interactive session without closing an open file?

Tags: python

What are the consequences of ending an interactive Python session without first closing an open file? I understand that closing files is necessary to free up memory and system resources, but would they continue to use such resources after the session has been ended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Python interpreter exits, it cleans up after itself (and after your program) and will close open files.